# function which gets an array as an input

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I want to make a function which gets an array (array1) with size (size1) as input and then call it in the main. Till now I reached at this point but something goes wrong with the program. Could anyone help me?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getdata( int array1[],int size1 ) {
    cin>>size1;
    for ( int i=0; i<size1; i++) {
        cin>>array1[i];
    }
}

int main () {
    int size1;
    int array1[size1];
    getdata(array1,size1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should include the programming language you are using

Comment: why is `size1` an argument to `getdata` if you read the size from `cin`?

Comment: in your main, `size1` is uninitialized so `array1` will contain an undefined number of elements

Comment: @GiacomoTecyaPigani,language is C++.

Comment: sorry, @RyanHaining I am confused with these.

Comment: Since you're writing C++ code, I strongly recommend investigating the use of `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bunch of errors here.

1. You define your size just as simple `int size1;`. It has undefined value, i.e. a random value.
2. With `int array1[size1]` you just create an array of a random size.
3. You pass size1 to a function `getdata` and ignore the value of a variable, overwriting it by a user's input.
4. Next, you iterate over an array of unknown size, assuming that user has guessed the size...

So, how to fix this. First of all, if the size of an array is not known in the compile time (at the time, you're writing a program) you need a dynamic array. You should use a vector class from a standard library. So, let's try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> getdata() {
    int size;
    std::cout << "Vector size: ";
    std::cin >> size;

    std::cout << "Please, enter exactly " << size  << " integers\n";
    std::vector<int> data(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size && std::cin; ++i) 
        std::cin >> data[i];
    return data;
}

int main () {
    std::vector<int> data = getdata();

    std::cout << "You've inputed:";
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << " " << data[i];

    std::cout << "\nThanks, and bye!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

---

## Update

Ok, let's try without vectors. But promise me, that you will not use it in production code and will forget it as soon, as you've learned vectors)).

And I would like to draw your attention to how I pass a size into a `getdata` function. I'm using a reference. That means that the value of size variable can be modified and the modification will be visible to the caller. So, `getdata` has two output parameters (and zero input). Maybe a cleaner solution will be to return a struct, containing a pointer and a size.

```
#include <iostream>

int *getdata(int &size) {
    std::cout << "Array size: ";
    std::cin >> size;

    std::cout << "Please, enter exactly " << size  << " integers\n";
    int *data = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size && std::cin; ++i) 
        std::cin >> data[i];
    return data;
}

int main () {
    int size = 0;
    int *data = getdata(size);

    std::cout << "You've inputed:";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        std::cout << " " << data[i];

    std::cout << "\nThanks, and bye!\n";

    // now we're responsible to free the memory
    delete[] data;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot,but we haven't studied vectors yet and it seems a bit confusing.

Comment: one more question, if i have to  use this array again in other functions within the same program is it recommended to delete it?i mean for the last step in main (delete [] data;.

Comment: It is a good practice to free the memory, once you do not need it. At least this explicitly states your intention to those who read your code.

Comment: But, this rises yet another question: who is responsible for the deletion, or, in other words, who owns the data. For example, if your function accepts a pointer to an allocated memory it seems unreasonable to expect, that the function code should be responsible to free the memory. It least it is not known how it was allocated (with, new, new[] or malloc). Another problem is when you pass some pointer to a function, and then delete the pointer, who can guarantee that function code didn't store the pointer in some global variable. Due to this problems, I recommended you to use vectors.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Please pay attention to the comments in the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* getdata(int& size) {

    // Read the size of the array.
    cin>>size;

    // Allocate memory for the array.
    int* array = new int[size];

    // Read the data of the array.
    for ( int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        cin>>array[i];
    }

    // Return the data.
    return array;
}

int main () {

    int size;

    // Get the data.
    int* array = getdata(size);

    // Use the data.
    //

    // delete the data
    delete [] array;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is interesting, how one can use an array without knowing its size?

Comment: @ivg An error of oversight. The answer is fixed now.

Comment: thanks,i understood this. although i should read more about pointers.

Comment: @ivg Thanks for that :) More importantly, thank you for pointing out the error and help make the answer better.

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't allow variable length arrays, array size must be a constant expression.
This statement is wrong:

```
int size1;
int array1[size1];
```

If the need be, use `vectors` or allocate the array on `heap`.

And in :

```
void getdata( int array1[],int size1 ) {
cin>>size1;
```

You are over-writing what `size1` contains.

Comment: Additionally, you overwrite the *local copy* of `size1`, because it was passed to `getdata()` by value, not by reference.